# Shell Script. Finish mysql dump before continuing script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

So I am trying to make a basic database backup script. It uses mysqldump and puts the data in a .sql file, which is then uploaded to dropbox.

My question is, how can I make sure the dump is finished before the upload starts?

```
mysqldump -u root -p<password> <database> > $DBFILE
dropbox_uploader.sh upload $DBFILE
```

Will it automatically wait for the dump to end, or do I need to make a while loop?
If the latter is the case, how do you go about that?

Answer (score 2):

*In general*, programs under *nix wait until completion before returning (though there are exceptions to this, mostly GUI applications). `mysqldump` follows this, therefore you do not have to do anything.